# Show the next opening day and hours

Tags: c#, razor

In my application I am passing opening and closing hours for an office. 
example like this

```
Monday    02:30PM  - 05:00PM
Tuesday   Closed
Wednesday 09:00AM  - 05:00PM
Thursday  Closed
Friday    Closed
Saturday  Closed
Sunday    Closed
```

The office can also open once a week the hours will look different.

```
Monday    02:30PM  - 05:00PM
Tuesday   Closed
Wednesday Closed
Thursday  Closed
Friday    Closed
Saturday  Closed
Sunday    Closed
```

**The code below only display the hours like above.**

My question is if it is Thursday, Friday, Saturday, or Sunday I want to display that the office will be open on Monday at 02:30PM. If it is on Tuesday it will show it will open on Wednesday at 9 AM.

**How do I calculate to show the next open day and hour of the office**

```
@foreach (var weekday in Model.OfficeHours.WeekdayHours)
{
    @weekday.DayName <br>
    @weekday.OpenTime.ToString("hh:mmtt")<br>
    @weekday.CloseTime.ToString("hh:mmtt")
}

public IEnumerable<DayHours> WeekdayHours { get; set; } 
public class DayHours
{
    public DayHours();

    public string DayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DayDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: `DateTime`'s have a `DayOfWeek` property. Maybe you can find the next day of the week using that? (i.e. `var nextWeekDay = Model.OfficeHours.WeekdayHours.Where(wh => wh.OpenTime.DayOfWeek == DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + 1)` (make sure to wrap back around when `DayOfWeek == 6`)

Comment: If you only care about time of day, not day of year, consider using `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an `IEnumerable`, you could a`Dictionary` to map `DateTime` objects to `DayHours` objects.

This way, you can check the next day with `DateTime.AddDays()` and retrieve it from the `Dictionary`

```
@foreach (var weekday in Model.OfficeHours.WeekdayHours)
{
    @weekday.Key <br> // Formerly DayDate, now the key of the Dictionary
    @weekday.Value.OpenTime.ToString("hh:mmtt")<br>
    @weekday.Value.CloseTime.ToString("hh:mmtt")
}

public Dictionary<DateTime,DayHours> WeekdayHours { get; set; } 
public class DayHours
{
    public DayHours();

    public string DayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
}
```

You could check `isClosed` and then show either `WeekDayHours[weekday.Key.AddDays(1)].Value...` or just `weekday.Value...`